# OpenGL rendering quality vs. number of vertices

Tags: c, opengl, 3d

I am coding a modern OpenGL application to visualize 3d atomic models (molecules, periodic systems ...) for chemistry and condense matter physics.
I started to work on this few years ago, the first version of my program was in old OpenGL now I am updating it to modern OpenGL.

I come with a question regarding the quality of the rendering of the OpenGL window. In the following examples I draw 3D cylinders and 3D spheres using instanced drawing, in this model to render the bonds I only draw one cylinder, then I translate/scale/rotate it properly in the vertex shader
to render all bonds, same goes for the sphere to render the atoms.
As you can see it works just fine, and the efficiency of the method is amazing and I can render models with hundreds of thousand of atoms smoothly.

However I noticed something weird, that somehow the quality of the rendering seems to be dependent on the number of vertices (objects, atoms and bonds) in the scene, obviously the number of triangles is the most important parameter but not the only one ... since the quality decrease when a lot of vertices are rendered ... please see the attached snapshots:

To render the spheres in the scene I am using 50x50 vertices, and 2x50 for the cylinders (GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP in both cases)

1) In this test model I load: 96 atoms, 512 half bonds, : ~ 291200 vertices:

[image: Initial model box]

2) I zoom in to focus on one selected atom and it surrounding, at this scale the result is impeccable:

[image: Zoom in initial model box]

3) I reset the view and use the builder in my program to increase the number of boxes
(I am simply doing replicas in the 3 direction of space) here I choose to do 20x20x20 replicas,
see the result bellow, the original box is highlighted.
In that scene there are 768000 atoms, 4096000 half-bonds, and thus: 291200x20x20x20 = 2329600000 vertices
quite a lot, yet it works, but something weird appears ...

[image: New model: 20 x 20 x 20 boxes]

4) I zoom in again on that particular area of the model I picked before and there is a decrease in quality in particular
in the areas where 3D objects (spheres/cylinders) superimpose/overlap ...

[image: Zoom in the 20 x 20 x 20 boxes model]

Can somebody explain to me what I see ?

Note 1: In the same window I can decrease the number of replicas back to the original box, zoom again
and see that the result is back to impeccable.

Note 2: the older version of my program still works fine (old OpenGL, using display list with glutsphere and glutcylinders),
I can do the same things, the rendering will take much much longer, but at the end of the process when I zoom in on the 20x20x20
boxes model, the results remains perfect, like for the single box model, and obviously I use same graphic card, driver and else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can somebody explain to me what I see ?

You're seeing the limited precision of the depth buffer. There are only so many bits you can work with and in a perspective projection a lonlinear scaling from Z distance to depth buffer value is applied.

The best course of action is to limit the near/depth range of the perspective projection matrix to what's going to be actually visible on screen, to make better use of the depth buffer. Also it's possible to linearize the depth buffer (but that comes with a performance hit). Also you could try to cleanly intersect the geometry where sticks and spheres meet, i.e. constrain the sphere's vertices to the cylinder surface where the sticks and similarly constrain the sticks' end vertices to the sphere where they meet. That way you avoid overlap and hence these artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer, I only wish I could understand it as clearly as it is written, now I get what is happening, not how to correct/improve it. I will focus on your first sentences and 'try to limit the near/depth range ...' the rest seems to be too much for me to handle. You are right about the perspective, I just change the projection to orthographic and the flickering disappear, could you by any change point me towards educational resources to understand this better and correct it ? ... Thanks again

Comment: @SébastienLeRoux: A very good explanation of the problem and several mitigation strategies on the projection/rendering pipeline setup are presented at http://dev.theomader.com/depth-precision/ (also check the chapters before and after). In general you should always place your far plane as distant as possible to the point of view and the near plane as close as possible. For what you do it's perfectly fine that you determine the (axis aligned) bounding box of your model (min / max for each sphere's coordinate -/+ sphere radius) and use the minimum/maximum distance to the corners after transform.

Comment: @SébastienLeRoux: Also if you want to Google around, the search terms to look for are "depth precision", "hyperbolic depth" and "linear depth".

Comment: @SébastienLeRoux: There's also an excellent explanation over at NVidia's dev blog https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized which in turn links to a great read by Emil Persson http://www.humus.name/index.php?ID=255

Comment: @SébastienLeRoux: Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: sorry about that, I am not really familiar with how things work here :-P